Failing to extract image from MP3
I have MP3 files with ID3 images of type "Other". I have tried a variety of methods to extract the images, including the suggestions at How to Extract Album Cover Image from MP3 file? To whit:
$ exiftool -a -u -g1 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3
$ ffmpeg -i 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3 qwert.png
$ eyeD3 --write-images=.    33-Kesh_Jig.mp3
$ eyeD3 --write-images=/tmp 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3
$ eyeD3 --write-images=tmp  33-Kesh_Jig.mp3
$ ffmpeg -i 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3 -an -c:v copy file.jpg
$ ffmpeg -i 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3 -an -c:v copy file.png
$ exiftool -a -G4 "-picture*" 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3
$ exiftool -picture -b 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3 > other.png
$ eog other.png
$ most other.png
$ exiftool -W %d%f_%t%-c.%s -b -preview:all DIR
$ exiftool -W %d%f_%t%-c.%s -b -preview:all /tmp
$ exiftool -W %d%f_%t%-c.%s -b -preview:all /tmp 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3
$ most 33-Kesh_Jig_Picture.dat

(most is simply a pager that automatically detects binary data and displays it in a hex dump format.)
Either I get no file at all, or I get a file which contains IHDR and Adobe XMP text strngs in it. When the file is played with VLC, the image shows up correctly. So it does not appear to be corrupt.
ffprobe has an error Unknown attached picture mimetype: , skipping. but exiftool -a -u -g1 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3 reports:
Picture MIME Type    :
Picture Type         : Other
Picture Description  : ‰PNG. .
Picture              : (Binary data 707734 bytes, use -b option to extract)


Can you append the output of ffprobe -hide_banner 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3? The line starting with "Stream #0:1: Video:" may be useful.

ffprobe -hide_banner 33-Kesh_Jig.mp3 2>&1↲
Unknown attached picture mimetype: , skipping.↲
Input #0, mp3, from '33-Kesh_Jig.mp3':↲
Metadata:↲
artist          : Matt & Shannon Heaton↲
album_artist    : Matt & Shannon Heaton↲
album           : In Harmony: Tune Cookbook for Learning↲
date            : 2022↲
Duration: 00:02:25.03, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 167 kb/s↲
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s↲
Metadata:↲
encoder         : LAME3.99r↲

Apparently, whichever software added that picture to the mp3 forgot to set the mimetype. This is not valid and you cannot expect this to work. The fact it works in VLC is sheer luck in the sense that VLC probably does not check the mimetype. The command exiftool -picture -b extracts the PNG body, but apparently the PNG header ended up in the "Picture Description", so you end up with an invalid file. Maybe if you append the body to the header, it will work. I cannot tell for sure without having the file.

If VLC displays it, you could still recover the image.  Run scrot -d 10 ~/cover.png then you have 10 seconds to make VLC full screen.

@JayCravens I don't want a screen shot. I want information about the resolution, etc. of the embedded image.

Well, this I understand. But if all else fails, it's retrievable.
